# How to apply modifications with init() method into toString()?

Tags: java

I have a problem when I want to display via `toString()` method the result of my program.

The result is "0.0" for my second input and I want the value I've entered.

```
public void init()
{
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        setName(input.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println("Enter number (double): ");
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (input2.hasNextDouble())
    {
        setNumber(input2.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

My `toString` method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return this.name + " - " + this.number;
}
```

Edit:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Branche 
{
    private String name;
    private double number;


    public Branche()
    {

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setName(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public void setNumber(double c)
    {
        this.number = c;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name + " - " + this.number;
    }

    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            setName(input.nextLine());
        }

        System.out.println("Enter number (double): ");
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (input2.hasNextDouble())
        {
            setNumber(input2.nextDouble());
        }
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestBranche 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Branche b1 = new Branche();

        b1.init();

        System.out.println(b1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `setNumber()`?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you're having? What does `setNumber` do and when do you call the `.toString()` method? Furthermore: there is no reason to use two scanners, one works just fine.

Comment: post the full code to get help.

Comment: What are you trying to output? You should store the input in a variable of some kind and then call `toString()` for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the code below and it is working, Please check your setname() and setNumber() function.

And you need only one Scanner object to take inputs, **No need** to create **multiple Scanner objects**

```
public class NewClass {

String name;
double number;

    public void init() {

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            setName(input.nextLine());
        }

        System.out.println("Enter number (double): ");

        if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
            setNumber(input.nextDouble());
        }
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setNumber(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " - " + this.number;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        NewClass obj = new NewClass();
        obj.init();
        System.out.println(obj);



    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
run:
Enter name: 
abc
Enter number (double): 
89.78
abc - 89.78
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: I've found the problem : I have to put "," and not "." for the number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess your problem is here:

```
if (input2.hasNextDouble())
    setNumber(input2.nextDouble());
}
```

It's likely that the scanner does not have a valid double.

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes:

```
// identation
public void init() {
    // You don't need and shouldn't open two scanners
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Makes your code clear by separating statements
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");  
    String iName = input.nextLine(); 
    setName(iName);

    System.out.println("Enter number (double): ");
    double iNumber = input.nextDouble();
    setNumber(input2.nextDouble());
}
```

And this is how `setNumber` should look:

```
public void setNumber(double number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

I've propositaly skiped the `hasNext()` methods since you are not providing any kind of retrial code (if your user inputs something else but a double -> `number` would not be set).

---

How to guarantee that the user entered something that can be parsed as `double`:

```
public double readDouble(String message, Scanner sc) {
    Double result = null;
    do {
        System.out.print(message + " (double): ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            result = Double.valueOf(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("* ERROR: Input is not a number");
        }
    } while (result == null);

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
double iDouble = readDouble("Enter number", sc);
```

This code avoids the many gotchas of `hasNextDouble()` and `nextDouble()`; for instance, a user can't attempt something like:

```
> Enter number (double): 123 something
```

Which would pass the `hasNextDouble` test but leave `something` on the stream.